# Audios Play in Loop

Tags: audio

I have a Macbook pro, running snow leopard.
My goal is to memorize around 4000 small pieces of audios ranging from 10 to 20 second each.
I want to memorize in sets of 20.

I would like to play these 20 in a loop, this is what I would like to achieve.

1. Play track 1 for n number of times
2. Play track 2 n number of times
3. Play track 1 & 2 n number of times
4. Play track 3 n number of times
5. Play track 1 & 2 & 3 n number of times

n is the variable I would like to be able to set, so that in the initial stages it will be high and later as I make progress I want to be able to minimize this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular programming langugage you'll be using?

Comment: An Object-Oriented language like java or c++ could be fine for your purpose

Comment: no I am not using any programming language, I was thinking if there was a way to do it in Mac Automator.

Comment: I found a easier solution for it, I created a playlist and then edited the playlist in excel to the order of repeat I want. However I did this in windows playlist, I am not sure if the equivalent exists in Mac